# Define/Create a BigQuery saved view's SQL query using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I want to defines/creates a BigQuery saved view's SQL statement using Apps Script but can't figure it out.

I've tried [following this guide](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#creating_a_view), but I can't seem to sort it out. 
What is the Apps Script function to define/update the SQL that defines/creates a saved view, call it `project.dataset.vSAVEDVIEW` in BigQuery?

Comment: Can you execute a query? You could use `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

Creating views via API uses the same method as `tables.insert`

> Call the [tables.insert](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert) method with a table resource that contains a view property.

So you could run a query as in [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery#run_query). And then save the data in a [new table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/insert).

Answer (score 0):

The issue started because storing to a new table when the view references google sheets based tables didn’t work.  Could not figure out the authentication issue, so I decided to save a view instead, which I couldn’t quite sort out at the time of asking this question. I did figure out how to do this finally.  And one thing I found was it was very important to put the table properties at the end, because when at the front, it creates a table instead of a view. I hope this helps people... here’s the structure of an Apps Script file that will write a view query to a saved view instead of a table:

```
// Choose the function to run from menu above.  
// You will need to delete the view first if it is already created.


// 1) This function deletes the already created saved view to make room for it to be created again.  function save_payments.vPayments_appscript() will fail if view already exists.

function remove_payments.vPayments_appscript() {
  var projectId = 'projectexample';
  var datasetId = 'payments';
  var tableId = 'vPayments_appsscript';
  table = BigQuery.Tables.remove(projectId,datasetId,tableId);
  }

// 2) This function creates the saved view in BQ

function save_payments.vPayments_appscript() {
  var projectId = 'projectexample';
  var datasetId = 'payments';
  var tableId = 'vPayments_appsscript';
  var table = {
    view: {
        query: 
        'SELECT * FROM `projectexample.payments.tPayments1` ' +
        'UNION ALL ' +
        'SELECT * FROM `projectexample.payments.tPayments2` ',
        useLegacySql: false
    },
    tableReference: {
      projectId: projectId,
      datasetId: datasetId,
      tableId: tableId,
    },
  };

  var queryResults = BigQuery.Tables.insert(table, projectId, datasetId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
`
```